# Email-to-case language dependent Case Priority?

Tags: email2case

Is it possible that Salesforce uses Labels of "Case Priority" in "Email-to-Case Settings" instead of API Name?

All email-to-case Cases have Priority API Name set to translated Case Priority Labels.

There is no way even to select these options, as they are created as "inactive".

[image]
[image]

Update: turns out it depends on launguage settings of default Case Owner. Which seems like an obvious bug, as I can't find a single mention about that anywhere.

Comment: You can check the label versus api name by looking at metadata type `CaseSettings`, subtype `EmailToCaseRoutingAddress` - see [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm?q=email-to-case#EmailToCaseSettings)

Comment: @cropredy It is <casePriority>Medium</casePriority> independent of language set of a user.

Comment: You should write a detailed answer as a service to the community, then accept the answer 2 days later (which is how long a self-answer must "percolate")